# Quantlib Bond PV01 by Tenor

Tags: interest-rates, python, quantlib

Having built a fixed rate bond object, and looking at [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37091/use-quantlib-python-to-calculate-swap-dv01) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279785/quantlib-building-key-rate-risks) , is there any way of retrieving the NPV impact of a repriced bond by bucket/tenor of the Spot Curve instead of getting a simple NPV figure?
The objective of this would be to have a baseline to apply a simple Value at Risk model to a portfolio of bonds, in which the key risk factors would be the **-PV01** figures by tenor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way, although you will have to code the logic. I'm assuming you want the tenor DV01 (change of market value for a shift of 1 bp in the market rate for a given tenor) and not the PV01 (present value of 1 bp).

Also, bear in mind Luigi's warning on the interpolation between the curve tenor points in one of the posts you mentioned.

```
import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

today = ql.Date().todaysDate()
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today
yts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
    ql.FlatForward(today, 0.01, ql.Actual365Fixed())
)

tenors = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
quotes = [ql.SimpleQuote(0.00) for n in tenors]
spreads = [ql.QuoteHandle(quote) for quote in quotes]
dates = [today + ql.Period(y, ql.Years) for y in tenors]

spreadedYts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
    ql.SpreadedLinearZeroInterpolatedTermStructure(yts, spreads, dates)
)
engine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(spreadedYts)

bond = ql.FixedRateBond(2, ql.TARGET(), 1e6, today, today + ql.Period(5, ql.Years), ql.Period('1Y'), [0.01], ql.ActualActual())
bond.setPricingEngine(engine)

npv = bond.NPV()
key_risk = []
for quote in quotes:
    quote.setValue(0.0001)
    key_risk.append( npv - bond.NPV() )
    quote.setValue(0.0)

plt.bar(tenors, key_risk)
```

Which would output:

[image]

You might also want to calculate it as the average of the change of market value for an up shift and a down shift

Comment: Thank you very much, David!